# quartz.net - question about schedulers

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler

I have a wcf service which sets up jobs for quartz. It's putting jobs in the db fine.

I then have a consol app running with the same config which i want to actually run the jobs.

I'm setting a trigger one minute from when the job is created but the consol app never runs it.

Is there some special config i need to run to get this to work?

Comment: To understand the things correct your service app is running and is configured via db...and you expect that the jobs you triggered are running on the command line app? How long does the CLI app live ?

Comment: got this working now. Just broke it down to the simplest working usage and built it back up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now workign wtih Mauricio to get the new castle quartz integration fimished.